# Moving Least Squares (MLS) surface reconstruction method

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use following code which states how a Moving Least Squares (MLS) surface reconstruction method can be used to smooth and resample noisy data, but it gives error like "pcl::IOException ("[pcl::PCDWriter::writeASCII] Input point cloud has no data!");".
I use same code from the link http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php .

```
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <pcl/surface/mls.h>

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud;

  // Fill in the cloud data
  cloud.width    = 5;
  cloud.height   = 1;
  cloud.is_dense = false;
  cloud.points.resize (cloud.width * cloud.height);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size (); ++i)
  {
    cloud.points[i].x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    cloud.points[i].y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    cloud.points[i].z = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
  }

  pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII ("test_pcd.pcd", cloud);
  std::cerr << "Saved " << cloud.points.size () << " data points to test_pcd.pcd." << std::endl;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size (); ++i)
    std::cerr << "    " << cloud.points[i].x << " " << cloud.points[i].y << " " << cloud.points[i].z << std::endl;

  // Create a KD-Tree
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  // Output has the PointNormal type in order to store the normals calculated by MLS
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal> mls_points;

  // Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused)
  pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls;
 
  mls.setComputeNormals (true);

  // Set parameters
  mls.setInputCloud (cloud.makeShared());
  mls.setPolynomialFit (true);
  mls.setSearchMethod (tree);
  mls.setSearchRadius (0.03);

  // Reconstruct
  mls.process (mls_points);

  // Save output
  pcl::io::savePCDFile ("bun0-mls.pcd", mls_points);
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59643/moving-least-squares-(mls)-surface-reconstruction-method./) by [Nihad](https://answers.ros.org/users/4554/nihad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Code looks ok, i'm guessing the problem is that your input point cloud has too few points (only 5) and with very sparse coordinates (you are randomizing them) so that mls can't find any surface in a radius of 3cm.

Also generally you should compute normals yourself, with `NormalEstimation` class and supply your normal to mls with `mls.setInputNormals` so that you can control how these normals are computed.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Tabjones](https://answers.ros.org/users/21948/tabjones/) with karma: 43 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) on 2018-08-02**:
Was there such a method in earlier times? I am looking for setInputNormals, but can't find it.